# Zurb Foundation top-bar menu not working on mobile display

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress, zurb-foundation

I am using the Zurb Foundation framework on a Wordpress site. The problem that I am having is with the responsive top-bar. When it goes into its mobile mode the menu doesnt work. It will not drop down on click. I have download their html templates, copied the code exactly and still it does not work.

Does anyone know how to fix it.

Answer (score 5):

I don't think you include the required javascripts for the TopBar component. I couldn't find it in your code.

Either reference `foundation.min.js` or `jquery.foundation.topbar.js`

Then you must initialize the menu with

```
$(document).foundationTopBar()
```

Answer (score 2):

Try loading foundation on DOM Ready.

```
$(function() {
    $(document).foundation();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

With zurb-foundation-4.0.9 you need to add this line to your html code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascripts/vendor/custom.modernizr.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

try to remove that part then test it. i have my site running on foundation 3. and the top bar is working. i had this issue before. do not include app.js when you are converting your html theme to wordpress theme.

Remove this

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://pinetowncpf.co.za/wp-content/themes/PinetownCPF/js/app.js"></script>
```

then test

regards eric